# Is there a widely used symbol for satoshi yet?

Tags: satoshi

Has a symbol been widely adopted for satoshi yet? I've seen Ș suggested but it's already a letter in Romanian. Ꞩ, Ȿ & ẜ (long s with stroke) all seem to be otherwise unused. Has anyone suggested using any of them?

Comment: related: https://medium.com/coinranking/satoshi-deserves-its-own-symbol-43138fe1ddf9, https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Satoshi_(unit), https://twitter.com/dickerson_des/status/1155560643635884032

Comment: Also related: https://twitter.com/murchandamus/status/1292966320732925952

Answer (score 1):

No.

> Satoshi is often abbreviated to sat or s, although no currency symbol
> has been widely adopted.

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Satoshi_(unit)

Answer (score 1):

I can't find where I first saw this symbol used for sats, but I've seen it a few times now and it is kind of growing on me:

**§**

Comment: That's called a section sign: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign. I wouldn't have a problem using it, but some would certainly complain, just like with the '฿' for Bitcoin itself, because it's the symbol for the baht (Thailand's currency).The symbol I'm referring to is .